# Need help reversing this loop

Tags: disassembly, c

I am having a difficult time reversing the following loop:

```
│       ┌─< 0x100001fea      723b           jb 0x100002027
│       │   0x100001fec      31db           xor ebx, ebx               ; ebx = 0
│       │   0x100001fee      41bc04000000   mov r12d, 4
│       │   0x100001ff4      6666662e0f1f.  nop word cs:[rax + rax]
│      ┌──> 0x100002000      418b441d00     mov eax, dword [r13 + rbx]
│      |│   0x100002005      b959b699f7     mov ecx, 0xf799b659
│      |│   0x10000200a      31c8           xor eax, ecx
│      |│   0x10000200c      418907         mov dword [r15], eax
│      |│   0x10000200f      4189041e       mov dword [r14 + rbx], eax
│      |│   0x100002013      4963dc         movsxd rbx, r12d
│      |│   0x100002016      4c8d6304       lea r12, [rbx + 4]
│      |│   0x10000201a      4c89ef         mov rdi, r13               ; const char * s
│      |│   0x10000201d      e8d0080000     call sym.imp.strlen        ; size_t strlen(const char *s)
│      |│   0x100002022      4939c4         cmp r12, rax
│      └──< 0x100002025      76d9           jbe 0x100002000
│       └─> 0x100002027      488b05d20f00.  mov rax, qword [reloc.__stack_chk_guard_0] ; [0x100003000:8]=0
```

r13 and r14 contain strings on the heap, and r15 contains a pointer to a buffer of size 4. I tried to write equivalent code in C, where second_string is r13, return_string is r14, value_holder is r15, and atoi_res is r12(d).

```
int ebx = 0;

atoi_res = 4;

while(1){
    ((int *)second_string)[ebx] ^= 0xf799b659;
    *value_holder = ((int *)second_string)[ebx];
    ((int *)return_string)[ebx] = ((int *)second_string)[ebx];

    ebx = atoi_res;
    if(strlen(second_string) > 8) break;
}
```

This does not seem right to me:

- There is no way to break out of the loop
- In the disas(I fixed this in the pseudocode) we are dereferencing a constant value of 8, then `lea`ing it again. Wouldn't this segfault?
- second_string is being XORed by this constant 4 bytes at a time, but the value that is supposedly contained (loaded in another part of the program) returns gibberish when XORed by this.

I can post more of the disassembly if needed. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

This is just taking a cstring pointed to by r13, xoring a dword at a time with the value 0xf799b659 and storing in the memory pointed to by r14.

I think your confusion is in what the `lea` instruction does. It simply loads the address of the memory instead of the memory value itself. In this case, it is just being used as a fast add operation. Compilers will often use it for simple addition or multiplication which is faster than an add/mul/etc instruction. In the case of `lea r12, [rbx + 4]`, this is doing just r12 = rbx + 4; there is no memory access at all. `rbx` is being used as a current byte index into the strings and `r12` is being used as the next byte index.